# Redirecting to Site whenever any AfterThrowing Aspect is called

Tags: aop

i am written one aspect i want whenever this is called  or any exception occurs , we redirect this to http://google.com

```java
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.ts.templateService.*.*(..))", throwing = "e")
public void LocalAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {

    Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
    String methodName = signature.getName();
    String stuff = signature.toString();
    String arguments = Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs());
    System.out.println("Got Exception in the Method: "
            + methodName + " with arguments "
            + arguments + "\nand the full toString: " + stuff + "\nthe exception is: "
            + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: **(a)** What is the question? you have not asked anything **(b)** Are you using AspectJ or Spring AOP? Neither your description nor your tags permit any conclusions.

Comment: Question : Whenver @AfterThrowing is called i want to redirect to some external url , i am using spring AOP.